# Tikz: foreach loop and hard-coded version producing different output

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

It seems to me that the following two pieces of tikz code should be equivalent; why do they produce different output?

Is there a way I can get the output of the hard-coded variant using a loop?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \m {3}
\foreach \s in {1,...,\m} {
  \node (tmpnode\s) at ({90 - 360/\m * (\s - 1)}:1cm) {$\s$};
}
\foreach \s in {1,...,\m} {
  \draw[bend left,->] let \n1={1+int(mod(\s,\m))} in (tmpnode\s) to (tmpnode\n1);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \m {3}
\foreach \s in {1,...,\m} {
  \node (tmpnode\s) at ({90 - 360/\m * (\s - 1)}:1cm) {$\s$};
}
\draw[bend left,->]  (tmpnode1) to (tmpnode2);
\draw[bend left,->]  (tmpnode2) to (tmpnode3);
\draw[bend left,->]  (tmpnode3) to (tmpnode1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: tikzpicture with \foreach]
[image: tikzpicture hard-coded]

Comment: You have to replace `\n1={1+int(mod(\s,\m))}` with `\n1={int(1+mod(\s,\m))}`. In the current version `\n1` takes the values `1.0`, `2.0` and `3.0` and `tmpnode1.0` is the same as `tmpnode1.east`.

Comment: That certainly solves it! As for the linked duplicate, the solution and underlying reason is the same, but the keyword there was `evaluate` rather than `let`.